# Windows installer database physical location

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Where does Windows installer store information about installed programs and components? Is it a file or registry values or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both but none of the locations are documented so it really shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the two questions together, it seems that the goal is to access information stored by Windows Installer. (See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).)

Windows Installer has an API that provides information through [C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions ([C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526782/2226988)) or [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390887%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908874/2226988)). Depending on the information needed, it can be quite simple to use. For example, starting with a ProductCode, features, feature states, components and component installed locations can be obtained.